# kestrel + nginx intermittent 502

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have an ASP.NET core 1.0 app running on ubuntu 16.04 behind `nginx/1.10.0`. However, I notice that intermittently nginx throws the following error (in nginx error-log)

```
2017/06/08 05:19:19 [error] 11572#11572: *119049 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: <ipaddress>, server: <servername>, request: "POST /<uri> HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/<uri>", host: "<servername>"
```

which results in a `502 Bad Gateway` to the client although the request completes successfully in the application

```
2017-06-08 05:19:14.399 [DBG] Executed action method "<Controller.Action>", returned result "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtRouteResult
```

Could this be an nginx configuration issue or ASP.NET/Kestrel issue? Can someone give me hints to debug this?

**Further notes:**

I also see the following in the application log just after request completion

```
2017-06-08 05:19:14.399 [DBG] Executed action method "<Controller.Action>", returned result "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtRouteResult
2017-06-08 05:19:18.632 [DBG] Some connections failed to close gracefully during server shutdown.
2017-06-08 05:19:22.402 [DBG] Hosting starting
2017-06-08 05:19:22.689 [DBG] Hosting started
```

and the nginx error is just around the same time `2017/06/08 05:19:19`

Also, normally in the logs I see messages around `Executing ObjectResult` and `Executed` time etc. which I don't see with the above request

```
2017-06-08 00:10:14.391 [DBG] Selected output formatter '"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter"' and content type '"application/json"' to write the response.
2017-06-08 00:10:14.391 [INF] Executing ObjectResult, writing value "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext".
2017-06-08 00:10:14.504 [INF] Executed action "<Controller.Action>" in 1875.3845ms
```

Comment: In your .NET app, are you using `async`/`await` for e.g. IO stuff? Are there any tasks that you fire off and never `await`? One potential cause of early closed connections could be that the framework assumes you're done and shuts down the request pipeline, although there are still asynchronous actions running. If resources that those async actions rely on are deallocated, they'll crash - but not have anywhere to report it since there's no awaiter.

Comment: Thanks @TomasLycken. Yes I do use `async/await` but don't have any `Task` I don't `await`

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue using the same setup. I am using Nancy instead of MVC though.

My setup worked fine for at least a month and then yesterday night it suddenly stopped working